# Will things spawn in a monster spawner on peaceful mode on survival?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I go near a monster spawned and I am on survival peaceful mode........will it still spawn what is in the spawner? I haven't tried this because I don't want to loose all of my stuff that is on me!

Answer (score 2):

No, peaceful mode prevents hostile monsters from spawning.

Comment: I think the mobs spawn but instantly deletes them